# how to decode_entities in utf8

Tags: perl, utf-8, decode, html-entities

In perl, I am working with the following utf-8 text:

```
my $string = 'a 3.9 k&#8486; resistor and a 5 µF capacitor';
```

However, when I run the following:

```
decode_entities('a 3.9 k&#8486; resistor and a 5 µF capacitor');
```

I get

```
a 3.9 kΩ resistor and a 5 ÂµF capacitor
```

The `Ω` symbol has successfully decoded, but the `µ` symbol now has gibberish before it.

How can I use decode_entities while making sure non-encoded utf-8 symbols (such as `µ`) are not converted to gibberish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Encode CPAN library.  If that is true, you can try this...

```
my $string = "...";
$string = decode_entities(decode('utf-8', $string));
```

This may seem illogical.  If Perl is natively UTF-8 itself, why should you need to decode a UTF-8 string?  It is simply another way of telling Perl that you have a UTF-8 value that it needs to interpret as natively UTF-8.

The corruption you are seeing is when a UTF-8 value doesn't have the rights bytes recognized (it shows "0xC1 0xAF" when Dumpered; after the above change, it ought to show "0x1503", or some similar concat'ed bytes) .

There are a ton of settings that can affect this in perl.  The above is most likely the right combination of changes that you need for your given settings.  Otherwise, some variation (swap encode with decode('latin1', ...), etc.) of the above should solve the problem.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. I will accept the answer when I can in a few minutes. Oddly, when I now run `url_encode($string)` later in the script, I now get a "wide character" warning. But I suppose that's an entirely new question.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a very well-phrased question. You didn't tell us where your `decode_entities()` function comes from and you didn't give a simple example that we could just run to reproduce your problem.

But I was able to reproduce your problem with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use HTML::Entities;

say decode_entities('a 3.9 k&#8486; resistor and a 5 µF capacitor');
```

The problem here is that by default, Perl will interpret your source code (and, therefore, any strings included in it) as ISO-8859-1. As your string is in UTF8, you just need to tell Perl to interpret your source code as UTF8 by adding `use utf8` to your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use utf8; # Added this line

use HTML::Entities;

say decode_entities('a 3.9 k&#8486; resistor and a 5 µF capacitor');
```

Running this will give you the correct string, but you'll also get a warning.

> Wide character in say

This is because Perl's IO layer expects single-byte characters by default and any attempt to send a multi-byte character through it is seen as a potential problem. You can fix that by telling Perl that STDOUT should accept UTF8 characters. There are many ways to do that. The easiest is probably to add `-CS` to the shebang line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -CS

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use utf8;

use HTML::Entities;

say decode_entities('a 3.9 k&#8486; resistor and a 5 µF capacitor');
```

Perl has great support for Unicode, but it can be hard to get started with it. I recommend reading [perlunitut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) to see how it all works.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. Without `use utf8` perl interprets the input file as just being bytes, not as ISO-8859-1.